# 外部リンクへの遷移後に特定の位置までスクロールさせるにはどうすればいいですか？

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

外部リンクへ飛ばしたときに、リンク先のアンカーの位置がずれて表示されます。
リンク先のアンカーの位置がきちんと頭だしされるように調整したいです。

外部リンクへの遷移後に特定の位置までスクロールさせるにはどうすればいいですか？
html,cssでできるのがよいですが、
できなければjs,jqueryでもよいです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: もし可能であれば、問題が再現するコードを追記していただけませんか？

Comment: リンク先サイトのコードは質問者さんが変更できますか？

Comment: @int32_t できないです。

Comment: 可能なことは、`id` 属性などが適用された要素にリンクすることだけです。そのため、質問者さんの実現したいことは、行なえないように思います。なぜそのようなことがしたいのですか？代替可能な手段があるかもしれません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

リンク先のページの問題ですので、原則的にはリンク元のページからは制御できません。

例外として、「リンク元とリンク先が同一オリジン」かつ「`<iframe>`や`window.open()`など、リンククリック後もリンク元ページが残っていてリンク先の`window`オブジェクトが入手可能」な場合はリンク元のページのコードでなんとか調整できる可能性があります。